# How to align characters and inline-blocks with paddings to the bottom with css?

Tags: css

As you can see, `.button` doesn't align to the bottom of `.row` with other elements when you add padding.

```css
a {
  display:inline-block;
}
.button{
  padding:5px;
  background:#ccc;  
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    some regulars texts
    <a href="#">hello this is title</a>
    <a class="button" href="#">add</a>
</div>

<div class="row">
    another some regulars texts
    <a href="#">hello this is another title</a>
    <a class="button" href="#">add</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to put the button bellow the statement?

Comment: @Fil no, I want the button to be in the same line. and its bottom(not its content bottom) align to the `.row` bottom

Answer (score 0):

ofcourse if u give padding allside it wont if u dont want bottom just add
the style

`padding-bottom:0px !important`

**or**

```
.button{
  padding:5px 5px 0px 5px;
  background:#ccc;  
}
```

Comment: but I think without bottom padding it doesn't look very nice.

Comment: then give padding to all elemnts so it will be equal to see

Comment: how do u expect then u want bottom aslo space and wants to allign same line , if u give line-height also will be same